# $in aggregation doesnt work with arrays not having distinct values

Tags: php, mongodb

$in aggregation doesnt return true if the searched value is more than one time present in the searching array.

Consider the following records

```
{ "_id" : 1, "location" : "24th Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "apples", "oranges", "bananas" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "location" : "36th Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "bananas", "pears", "grapes" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "location" : "82nd Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "cantaloupes", "watermelons", "apples" ] }
```

Now applying this $in aggregation

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "store location" : "$location",
      "has bananas" : {
        $in: [ "bananas", "$in_stock" ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

returns

```
{"_id" : 1, "store location" : "24th Street", "has bananas" : true }
{ "_id" : 2, "store location" : "36th Street", "has bananas" : true }
{ "_id" : 3, "store location" : "82nd Street", "has bananas" : false }
```

but if the record contains same multiple values in the array

```
{ "_id" : 1, "location" : "24th Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "bananas", "bananas", "bananas" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "location" : "36th Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "bananas", "pears", "grapes" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "location" : "82nd Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "cantaloupes", "watermelons", "apples" ] }
```

it returns

```
{"_id" : 1, "store location" : "24th Street", "has bananas" : false}
{ "_id" : 2, "store location" : "36th Street", "has bananas" : true }
{ "_id" : 3, "store location" : "82nd Street", "has bananas" : false }
```

Record 1 should also return true, because it has the value banana in it. but it doesnt return

Comment: I tried at my end and I am getting correct results.

Comment: it doesnt work with mongodb php

Comment: ...aggregation pipeline...
,
array('$addFields' => array(
        "isThere" => array(
            '$in' => array(array(new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($_SESSION["userid"])), array('$arrayField'))
        )
    )
,
...aggregation pipeline..

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DXUiY48EPeN

Comment: array('$addFields' => array(
        "arrayField" => array('$ifNull' => array(('$arrayField'), array()))
    )),

Added to the pipeline... it works now...

Comment: First the field exists has to be checked and if not a dummy field has to be added in order for the $in to work.. orelse it simply considers it as empty array and doesnt work